# Sanitize DOM IDs

Tags: ruby, html, ruby-on-rails, regex, dom

I needed to create a method that would sanitize DOM IDs based on the HTML 4 criteria (yeah, HTML 5 is a lot looser). Does this make sense? Did I get too cute with making it concise? Am I totally misinterpreting what a DOM id is? I presumed it meant something like `<p id="annoying_paragraph"></p>`.

```
def sanitize_dom_id(candidate_id)
  #The HTML 4.01 spec states that ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), 
  #hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).
  prefix = candidate_id.slice!(0)
  #replace invalid prefix with Z_
  prefix = "Z_" if [/[a-zA-Z]/].nil? 

  #replace invalid internal characters with underscore "_"
  candidate_id.gsub!(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.:_-]/,"_")
  "#{prefix}#{candidate_id}"
end
```

Sample input and output:

> ```
> sanitize_dom_id("1htmlid")
> Should result with "Z_htmlid"
>
> sanitize_dom_id("html id")
> Should result with "html_id"
> ```

Comment: are you using Rails? You know there is such helpers in Rails?

Comment: @jipiboily.com Can you link to them?

Comment: There is this exact method in Rails: [sanitize_dom_id](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-sanitize_dom_id)

Comment: @Cygal The helper he mentioned just returns the same id entered. I am working on the TODO to add in the cleansing process to the helper he brings up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation, the early return and extra variable are probably a matter of taste. 
That early return doesn't feel idiomatic.

It attempts to remove invalid characters at the start of the candidate_id, until it finds valid ones. It will only prefix if it can't find a valid id somewhere in the candidate.

```
def sanitize_dom_id(candidate_id)
  # Replace non-ascii chars with an ascii version
  # See ActiveSupport::Inflector#transliterate
  sanitized_id = transliterate(candidate_id)

  # Replace invalid characters with underscore "_"
  sanitized_id.gsub!(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.:_-]/,"_")

  # Remove invalid (non Alpha) leading characters 
  valid_id = sanitized_id.gsub(/^[^a-zA-Z]+/, '')

  return valid_id unless valid_id.empty?

  # Prefix the ID with a known valid prefix.
  "n_" + sanitized_id
end
```

Example output.

```
"100-1012foo foo-bar f-=-=- ba9 --dash 9999 66-66".split.map {|id| sanitize_dom_id id }
>> ["foo", "foo-bar", "f-_-_-", "ba9", "dash", "n9999", "n66-66"]
```

Comment: About the early return: why don't you declare a prefix like it has been done in the question?

Comment: I could probably replace the last 2 lines with a ternary operator, but I dont think it would be as clear.

valid_id.empty? ? "n_" + sanitized_id : valid_id

Comment: What about the same thing with if/else? :)

Comment: On second thought, I think I prefer the early return, but that it also a matter of taste. Using if/else to determine a return value, but without an explicit return always throws me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that your `'Z_'` prefix replacement works: `[/[a-zA-Z]/]` is an array consisting of one `Regexp`, and that array is never `nil`.

Your implementation using `#slice!` is tricky to follow.  I suggest writing it this way:

```
def sanitize_dom_id(name)
  # http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name
  #
  # ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and
  # may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]),
  # hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
  name.sub(/\A[A-Z]/i, 'Z_').gsub(/[^A-Z0-9.:_-]/i, '_')
end
```

Note that inside a character class, `.` is taken literally and does not need to be preceded by a backslash.

You haven't explained why you need this function, which makes it hard to assess whether it is suitably designed.  I'd like to point out that it is possible for multiple input strings to map to the same sanitized output.  That might be an undesirable property — in which case you should think of this more as an escaping function than a sanitizing function.